# SMTP secure connection and authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have been mulling over this for a few days, and without success I cannot pinpoint the exact cause for my code not authenticating with the smtp gmail server. What I have made sure to do:

- set gmail up to accept less secure apps
- 2 way verify is OFF
- Captcha use is OFF
- iis 6 smtp
- webpage coded properly using asp.net C#
- port 587 outbound and inbound set to allow all

here is the code

.aspx.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Net;


public partial class Contact : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage;
        SmtpClient smtpClient;

        try
        {
            mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add("013blitz@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("crebrum.web.design@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "ASP.NET e-mail test";
            mailMessage.Body = "Hello world,\n\nThis is an ASP.NET test e-mail!";

            smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpClient.Port = 587;

           NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("crebrum.web.design@gmail.com", "Meowqwe789doG");

           smtpClient.Credentials = nc;


            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;



            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;



            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            //Response.Write("E-mail sent!");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }



}
```

HTML

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Contact.aspx.cs" Inherits="Contact" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="contentbody" Runat="Server">



    <div class="contact">
        <div class="contact-heading text-center">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                        <div class="headingpng">
                            <img src="img/heading.png" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="contact-form" class="clearfix">
        <h4 class="text-center">
            Please fill in the contact form below with any questions you may have.
        </h4>
         <ul id="errors" class="">
             <li id="info">
                 There were some problems with your form submission:
             </li>
         </ul>
        <p id="success">
            Thanks for your message! We will get back to you ASAP!
        </p>
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="John Doe" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
            <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Tb_Name" ></asp:TextBox>

            <label for="email">Email Address: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="johndoe@example.com" required="required" />

            <label for="telephone">Telephone: </label>
            <input type="tel" id="telephone" name="telephone" value="" />

            <label for="enquiry">Enquiry: </label>
            <select id="enquiry" name="enquiry">
                <option value="general">General</option>
                <option value="sales">Sales</option>
                <option value="support">Support</option>
            </select>

            <label for="message">Message: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your message must be greater than 20 charcters" required="required" data-minlength="20"></textarea>

            <span id="loading"></span>
            <%--<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button" />--%>
            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn_Submit" Text="Submit" OnClick="Btn_Submit_Click" />
            <p id="req-field-desc"><span class="required">*</span> indicates a required field</p>
        </div>
</div>



</asp:Content>
```

As I have stated I have searched all over for the fix, what I have come up with in the end is that I am doing the html and c# properly, everything seems to work up to the catch (Exception ex) code line, which then sends me this

[System.Net.Mail.SmtpException] = {"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"}

If anyone has any suggestions that would be great!

Comment: Change your gmail passowrd now, as you have let the world know how to get into your email. If you post code like this, make sure you mask the password. Do it now before trying to fix the issue.

Comment: BTW, your `SmtpClient` and `MailMessage` need to be in `using` blocks.

Comment: Yes that was a rookie mistake haha, oh man, facepalm goes here. Anyway it is a dummy address so if anyone did get in, there is nothing to see anyhow. On the other hand I need to know where to post a solution to this problem. I was unable to get it to work, and I would love to leave something for everyone that comes into this issue using Windows 7. I found something that works perfectly for those unable to send smtp requests to gmail or , anywhere else, despite the code being ok. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change default credentials to true.

```
 smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

Here is the complete code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Btn_Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mailMessage;
        SmtpClient smtpClient;

        try
        {
            mailMessage = new MailMessage();
            mailMessage.To.Add("013blitz@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.To.Add("crebrum.web.design@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("crebrum.web.design@gmail.com");
            mailMessage.Subject = "Change your password";
            mailMessage.Body = "Hello Crebrum,\n\nPlease change your password for crebrum.web.design@gmail.com!" +
                "You posted the password on stack overflow and anyone can access your email now.";

            smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            smtpClient.Port = 587;

            NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential("crebrum.web.design@gmail.com", 
                "{Here is where I masked your password. You are welcome}");

            smtpClient.Credentials = nc;


            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;



            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;



            smtpClient.Send(mailMessage);

            //Response.Write("E-mail sent!");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Response.Write("Could not send the e-mail - error: " + ex.Message);
        }

    }


}
```