# 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first

Tags: c#, ssl, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I'm trying to send email through C#. Although I beleive I've done everything right, it still throws this exception :

**"The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at"**

At first I thought, it could be a zone/ip/region problem... But when i logged into gmail, there wasn't any warning of that. And to be sure, i've uploaded a file to a website to check from there, still the error was thrown.

Than I've tried changing the port to 465. It didn't work either.

I've first tried with accounts that are managed by a Google Apps account. So I thought it could be it, but it wasn't either...

I'm truly out of ideas right now.

Any of you have an idea ?

Here is the example code :

```
   SmtpClient sm = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);

        sm.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("blabla@gmail.com","**");
        sm.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        sm.EnableSsl = true;
        sm.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        sm.Send("blabla@gmail.com","blabla2@tr3reklam.com","Test","Test");
```

** Note **
I've checked the account name and password, they both are right.

Comment: do a google search there are plenty of working examples out there.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27870353/smtp-secure-connection-and-authentication it appears that you are missing something also wrap that code around a try{}catch{} and you are not building the message correctly from first glance

Comment: sorry ! i've forgot to mention that, but yes, i've checked

Comment: Beleive me I've searched... I've tried this with 3 different accounts, there is no 2-step ver. on any of them, there can be no "less-secure apps" settings when using Google Apps, I've used both 587 and 465 ports, tried with different settings such as "UseDefaultCredentials=true" or "EnableSsl=false"... None of those work.  Also i am using this block in a try-catch block.

Comment: is it your email account..? check it manually by signing in and see if you can get in.. if not then the account is probably locked from too many bad attempts. did you look at link.. perhaps you should try some working examples the link is in my initial comment..

Comment: Yes all of them are mine. And i can manually sign into all. There are no blockages.

Comment: I work with similar code to what I posted in the link and I have zero issues .. have you tried a different approach...

Comment: What do you mean by different approach ?

Answer (score 1):

"Access for less secure apps" must be enabled for the Gmail account used by the NetworkCredential using [Google's settings page](https://www.google.com/settings/u/5/security/lesssecureapps).

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: The link is not to documentation. It's to the actual place you set that option. "Link-only" is therefore quite wrong; the answer contains everything any answer could.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by 2-Step Verification after all !

It is odd, but without turning on "Allow users to be able to turn on 2-Step verification on" option set to true, I couldn't send any mails.

2-Step verification is still off for the accounts but, probably allowing users to choose for themselves make some security settings in the background.

I couldn't find any documentation about this but I can send now...

Answer (score 0):

Put the code sm.UseDefaultCredentials = false; before sm.Credentials = ...