# Sending email back to me after user runs my program

Tags: c#

Is this possible? I was able to do this with my self with this code:

```
string fromaddr = "olivearlerel@gmail.com";
string toaddr = "olivearlerel@gmail.com";//TO ADDRESS HERE
string password = "password";

MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
msg.Subject = "Hope you got this!";
msg.From = new MailAddress(fromaddr);
string externalip = new WebClient().DownloadString("icanhazip.com");
msg.Body = externalip;
msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(toaddr));
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
smtp.Port = 587;
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.EnableSsl = true;
NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential(fromaddr, password);
smtp.Credentials = nc;
smtp.Send(msg);
```

However, when my Skype friend runs this program (So that the program sends me his IP address through email), he gets an exception and I have a feeling its because he can't access my email to send it to me.

Is there any settings I need to change in my gmail account so that the program he runs can log into it? Or is there a different method for this? This would help greatly, thanks!

Exception he had:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.Mail.SmtpException' occurred in 
>   System.dll
>
> Additional information: The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the 
>   client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a 
>   STARTTLS command first. u21sm2465240pfg.121 - gsmtp

Comment: Please add the exception details.

Comment: give exception, not feeling.

Comment: And add the relevant code to the question, not to the comments.

Comment: You're sending a (rather easily decompilable) program with your gmail username & password hardcoded in it to other people?

Comment: Added the exception and updated Question.

Comment: Yes I am but the gmail account doesn't really matter to me, it's just a dummy to send me the email with his public IP. (we tested it together)

Comment: probably you need to be logged in to google from the computer you use first ?

Comment: If this is a friend on Skype, why can they not just manually visit the IP checking site and/or just have the program spit out their IP address and have them pass it back to you via Skype?

Comment: related (or duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462628/the-server-response-was-5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first-i16sm1806350 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664320/5-7-0-must-issue-a-starttls-command-first